# Can we use .wma sound files in andengine?

Tags: android, audio, andengine, wma

I am trying to use one sound file with wma extension. But when I try to play it, it doesn't play. Do andengine support .wma extension files?

```
Sound sound = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(activity.getSoundManager(), activity, "mfx/sound111.wma");
sound.play();
```

But it doesn't play.

Comment: .wav format support depend on some libraries not always available on Android devices

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer. I will have to use mp3 or ogg rather than wav format. Because  wma is a closed format and it's support depend on some libraries not always available on Android devices, and they're not part of the AOSP (Android Open Source Project) tree itself.

Comment: I suggest that use ogg format because the smaller file size while keeping quality

Comment: Me too, unfortunately not my graphics and sound team.